# In Mui Autocomplete how to call a function after selecting an option (not simultaneously)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

After doing:

1. Clicking on `Autocomplete` input
2. Moving between options by using `arrow` keys
3. Selecting an option by pressing `enter` key

I want to call a function by pressing `enter` key again but I cannot find out how to do it.

I tried to use `onKeyDown` event on `Autocomplete`'s input but by selecting a value on pressing `enter` it calls the function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this feature I want to implement:

I keep an `isOpen` state for the `Autocomplete` and use `onClose` and `onOpen` events to change `isOpen` and on pressing keys in the input I check if the key code is `Enter` and `isOpen` is `false` then I call the method I want:

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
...

<Autocomplete
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField onKeyDown={(e)=> { 
          if(e.key === 'Enter' && !isOpen) filter()
        } />
      }
      onOpen={()=>setIsOpen(true)}
      onClose={()=>setIsOpen(false)}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this. `onChange` has following props:

`(event: any, value: string, reason: AutocompleteInputChangeReason)` and once suggestion is selected `reason` has value `reset`

```
(event: any, value: string, reason: AutocompleteInputChangeReason) => {

 

if (reason === "reset") {

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onChange prop in MUI Autocomplete. like:-

```js
<Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={[]}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      onChange={()=>console.log("changed")}
    />
```

Comment: No it does it simultaneously and not separately.
I want to call the function on pressing `enter` on certain circumstances which I described above

Comment: I have tested the code. onchange function is called only when option is selected or de-selected.

Comment: I know, but I'm looking for a way to implement pressing `enter` after you have selected an option and not when you select an option